# Variable in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to use variable in [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j) query?

For example [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql):

```
SET @id = 1;
SELECT @id;
+------+
| @id  |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

Is it possible to do something similar in [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j), like:

```
SET @id = 1;
WITH @id as id RETURN id;
```

PS: Reason - I have big and complicated query and to run this query couple times with different params I have to manually replace values in query, which is not efficient.

With these variables I wouldn't need to change query, just update variables values...

Comment: providing your query may be better at helping you debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) to a Cypher query. For example, if `id` is passed in as a parameter:

```
:param id => 1
RETURN $id
```

[UPDATE]

If a parameter (say, `propName`) specifies a property *name*, then you can use the `n[$propName]` syntax to *get* the specified property from `n`. But to *set* the property value you could use APOC procedures like [apoc.create.setProperty](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/).

Comment: how does that work? parameters cannot be used as property keys

Comment: you can, however do something like `n[$id]`

Comment: Your question did not mention the need to pass property names, but yes you can use the `n[$id]` syntax to *get* a property value but not *set* the value. To set the value with a dynamic property name you could use APOC procedures like [apoc.create.setProperty](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/).